# Dynamically add a xml defined layout at run-time outside of onCreate()

Tags: android

I have a custom ViewGroup (blue background) that when touched sometime during the app's life cycle, I want to add an arbitrary xml defined view layout (whitebox to be in foreground) to that custom view.

Is there any way to do this outside of the activity's onCreate?

whitebox.xml

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="100dp"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:background="#FFFFFF"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

TestDynamicLayoutActivity.java

```
package net.lapasa.testdynamiclayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestDynamicLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new MyCustomViewGroup(this));
    }
}
```

MyCustomViewGroup.java

```
package net.lapasa.testdynamiclayout;

import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyCustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup
{

    private Context context;

    public MyCustomViewGroup(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        View whiteBoxView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.whitebox, this);
        ViewGroup targetParent = (ViewGroup) whiteBoxView.getParent();
        targetParent.removeView(whiteBoxView);
        this.addView(whiteBoxView);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

The block of code in the ACTION_DOWN doesn't do anything except present a black screen =( What is going on?

Comment: you make sure that the layout - which needs to extend viewgroup - you want to add to has an id. then when you want to add something later you inflate it with layoutInflater i.e. getSystemService(Context.layoutInflator); and manually add what you want.

Comment: Is that not what I am already doing inside onTouchEvent()?

Comment: sorry your right i'd just debug your code to make sure that the layoutinflater is properly set. Ive never used the .from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I get that right - you just want to have some blue view containing a white view that shows up when the blue view is clicked?

Then it would be better not to implement your own `ViewGroup` but using one of the existing ones like `FrameLayout`. Set the layout's background to blue. Add a child `View` with it's background set to white and it's visibility set to `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE`.

Add a click handler to the `ViewGroup` that sets the visibility of your white `View` to `View.VISIBLE`.

You could do it like this:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

             android:background="#00f"
             android:onClick="onBlueClick"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <View android:id="@+id/whiteBox"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:visibility="gone"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

MyActivity.java:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  private View whiteBox;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    whiteBox = findViewById(R.id.whiteBox);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"}) // wired by layout xml
  public void onBlueClick(final View view) {
    if (whiteBox != null) {
      whiteBox.setVisibility(whiteBox.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One of the stipulations I defined is that it has to be outside of the onCreate(); Functionally that works but onCreate of Activity, i want to perform lazy instantiation. In your example whitebox has been loaded whether it will be used or not.

Comment: Then you can use a `ViewStub`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems changing your view hirarchy at runtime (though you must ensure to do your modifications on the UI thread). I think your example doesn't work because you are deriving from `ViewGroup` which ist just a stub that doesn't really layout it's child views. If you really want to go with a custom `ViewGroup` just to change the background color, derive from one that actually handles the layouting.

Comment: ViewStub looks like exactly what I want, thx! Also your right about the ViewGroup being too bare bones. I used FrameLayout and it does the layout-ing as you mentioned. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try call `invalidate()` after adding new view. And possible you have to override `layout()`, `measure()` and `draw()` methods for creating complete custom view.

Comment: Tried invalidate(). Doesn't work. If I overwrite layout, measure and draw of my custom view group, what exactly would I be doing?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html Here is instruction what you should do for implementing custom view